# Getting "too many arguments" exception in my code?

Tags: vb.net

I am using vb.net. I get a "too many arguments" error when I try to execute this code:

```
If System.IO.File.Exists("C:\Users\", My.User.Name, "Desktop\virus.exe") 
    Then

        RichTextBox1.AppendText(RichTextBox1.Text & "virus.exe" & Environment.NewLine)

    End If
```

Is there any way I can shorten this?

Comment: `,` does not concatenate strings, nor does it `Path.Combine(...)` them

Comment: I'd also suggest that you look up `append` in a dictionary, your are adding the entire text content to itself each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You have way too many arguments. `File.Exists` accepts only one.
- You need to use ampersand for concatenation, not commas.
- Use `Imports` to import namespaces to shorten your code and make it cleaner
- Also, you appending entire text box again.

Below is fix for all your problems

```
Imports System.IO 'this will allow for shorter code

Dim myFile as String = "C:\Users\" & My.User.Name & "\Desktop\virus.exe"
If File.Exists(myFile) Then
    ' This will append only new text, not all of the existing text    
    RichTextBox1.AppendText("File: " & myFile & Environment.NewLine)

End If
```

Comment: good post. On a side note, you don't have to concatenate the `My.User.Name` and such to get to that folder (Desktop). You can get rid of that whole whole thing with `My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop` which will make it less to error's...

Comment: @436f6465786572 This is fine. Although this was the least problem of the asking party :o)

Answer (score 0):

Another way that makes this easy is by using `Linq`... Also you can use the `My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop` to go to the desktop and not have to worry about `My.User.Name` and concatenating strings ...

**Here's a simple function** - if you would want to use it again somewhere else...

```
 Public Shared Function DoesFileExist(ByVal Directory As String, ByVal FileName As String) As Boolean
    Return New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Directory).GetFiles(FileName, IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories).Any
 End Function
```

**Usage Example**

```
 If DoesFileExist(yourdirectory, yourfilename) Then
    MsgBox("Exists!")
 End If
```

**Or just in one line...**

```
 If New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(yourdirectory).GetFiles(yourfilename, IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories).Any Then RichTextBox1.AppendText blah blah...
```

Comment: One of the joys of vb is being able to make code read like natural language (at least in English)... might be better to name your function "FileExists".

Comment: @HeyHeyJC why would I do that when I can name it: `FileExist`? :)

Comment: It's all just IMHO, but... because "If file exists" reads as okay'ish English, and "If file exist" doesn't (for the same reason, the version which takes several files as arguments would be called "FilesExist").

Comment: Why you using `CBool`? Extension method `Any()` already return `Boolean`

Comment: @Fabio just a habit I guess, I knew that... I have option strict on, so when typing the return I went ahead and started wrapping it. Thanks!